# Object reference not set to an instance of an object. - DefaultValue

Tags: c#

Say I have three classes A, B and C and they are nested in such a manner that I can access C through B through A (ie. A.B.C). If I'm trying to access a simple property of C, say Id type int, and I haven't instanciated a new instace of B in A (or C in B) I would get an 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' error.

What I'd like to know is if there is a simple way of saying get me A.B.C.Id and if you can't becuase something is null along the way give me a default value.

```
var myId = A.B.C.Id <some operator> -1;
```

At the moment I'm doing something like this and it just feels horrible.

```
var myId = A == null ? -1 : A.B == null ? -1 : A.B.C == null ? -1 : A.B.C.Id;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C# is no special syntax which can do what you want to do.

But there is some architectonic ways, how to do it.

You can use a [Null Object Design Pattern](http://www.google.cz/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=1&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FNull_Object_pattern&ei=S3SBSpW1BJTFsgby9JHMCQ&usg=AFQjCNEksAKL-3RfMRJIDnCX3QVzj-xvng&sig2=coIQblzH-ah8iinAm2lKKg)
or you can extend the A, B, C classes with extension methods which allows null:

```
var myId = A.BOrNull().COrNull().IdOrNull();

public class A {
    public B B { get; set; }
}
public static class AExtensionMethods {
    public static B BOrNull( this A a ) {
        return null != a ? a.B : null;
    }
}

public class B {
    public C C { get; set; }
}
public static class BExtensionMethods {
    public static C COrNull( this B b ) {
        return null != b ? b.C : null;
    }
}

public class C {
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
public static class CExtensionMethods {
    public static int? IdOrNull( this C c ) {
        return null != c ? (int?)c.Id : null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm accepting this as the answer to my question due to the fact TcKs went to the greatest length to provide a solution to my situation. I appriciate that in an ideal world I would refactor and get out of this situation but unfortunatly I don't work there :).

Answer (score 4):

references C by going through A or B or both breaks the [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) which is bad practise. If something is needs to be referenced that way have a empty constructor that builds the connections that way.

Comment: Depends on the strictness of your interpretation of the Law of Demeter. Does `person.Name.FirstName`, `person.Name.LastName` violate the Law? I think most people would not be that strict.

Comment: I think he means with logic classes. Anything which contains methods I guess. I didn't know there was a written rule +1;

Comment: @Ruben the Law of Demeter can be broken ,sometimes it has to, but if you break it I would recommend looking at your structure and seeing if you can structure your objects so that you don't because the less you break the law of demeter the more likely your code will be testable because you can inject dependencies a lot cleaner into it.

Comment: It's not about breaking the Law. The number of dots is not a strict measure of whether you violate the Law of Demeter. Sometimes an 'object' consists of several logical parts, which you can group as subproperties, merely to provide a better logical design of your objects. Even though your dotcount is greater than 1, you're not violating the Law itself. Well, depending on your interpretation that is.

Comment: Interesting. Not read this before but can appriciate the rule and its reason for being, however refactoring is not an option and as mentioned in Damien's answer an object property of null is valid in my situation as it being null is driving additional logic.

Comment: @Ruben you've also hit the situation I'm in with these sub-objects actaully being no more than logical parts of a very large object.

Answer (score 1):

Look into [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) which will create C in B and B in A when you make a new instance of A. Or just put the code to create such instances in the constructor of your class. (So Create B in A() and C in B())

The reason it feels wrong is because, as others have pointed out, you should not be in the situation where this can occur.

Comment: It won't solve ID being null, but it will solve the problem of the dependent classes (in this case, B and C) being null as they will be created with A.

Comment: I.E A depends on B so that is created automatically when A is. B depends on C and so that is created when B is.

Comment: I understand the question as "the B or C can be null and it is valid state". It's the cause of my question.

Comment: @TcKs you're right I asked the question as the sub-object state of null is valid. Being null would mean "doesn't exist" and it shouldn't have to therefore DI wouldn't work for me.

Comment: Well ok, It's kinda weird state for it to be in. Hence my own confusion :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have to go that deep in you might want to create a property in A that gives you null or B.C.Id.

Comment: I would say do it deeper : 
A.I get {return B == null ? -1 : B.I} 
B.I get {return C == null ? -1 : C.I} 
but this is not an option if you hve a lot of properties

Answer (score 1):

This is a good fit for the [Null Object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) design pattern.

Basically, define NullB like this:

```
public class NullB : B
{
    public override C C
    {
        get { return new NullC(); }
    }
}
```

Then define NullC thusly:

```
public class NullC : C
{
    public override int Id
    {
        get { return 0; }
    }
}
```

This obviously requires that the classes in question have virtual members, but it's much safer that way. Then, when you have real instances of B and C, you just use and return those instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use properties to check if the requested clas is null or not. If it is it will create a new instance of the class.

```
class ClassA
{
    private ClassB m_ClassB = null;
    public ClassB B
    {
        get
        {
            //check if we already have an instance of the class.
            //if not create it
            if (m_ClassB == null)
            {
                m_ClassB = new ClassB();
            }
            return m_ClassB;
        }
    }
}

class ClassB
{
    private ClassC m_ClassC = null;
    public ClassC C
    {
        get
        {
            //check if we already have an instance of the class.
            //if not create it
            if (m_ClassC == null)
            {
                m_ClassC = new ClassC();
            }
            return m_ClassC;
        }
    }
}

class ClassC
{
    private int m_Id = 123;
    public int ID
    {
        get
        {
            return m_Id;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can just access what you need like this

```
 CLassA A = new ClassA();
 int id = A.B.C.ID;
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try this code:

```
var myId = -1;
try
{
  myId = A.B.C.Id;
}
catch (NullReferenceException e)
{
  myId = -1;
}
```

Comment: -1 this is VERY BAD way, how to do it.
It makes program slowly and the debuging will be much harder if exceptions will be thrown often.

Comment: It is bad practice to use exceptions to control program flow. In this case you can easily check for null first to avoid the exception being thrown.

Comment: Don't use exceptions as control flow. Your code will be more readable, and maintainable if you spell out the checks for null.

Comment: -1 Using exceptions to control program flow is really bad practice. You can do way better checking for null or creating an instance of teh class if it does not exist.

Comment: You shouldnt use catch blocks to manage exceptions you already expect. Setting it to -1 means you know what to expect. In that case check for null exceptions and set the myId to -1 on that condition.